# MSMQ Remote Receive error "The specified format name does not support the requested operation"

Tags: sql-server, msmq, windows-server-2012-r2, transactional-queue

So ran into this weird issue. I am trying to receive a message from a non-authenticated transactional msmq. My environment is:

- Server where the queue is a Windows Server 2012 R2. This is also the DB server (SQL Server)
- Server where the client application is installed is also a Windows Server 2012 R2

I am trying to send message from SQL Server to MSMQ (which works fine). But whrn the client application tries to receive the message using the code below it throws the error I mentioned in the title.

```
private void OnPeekCompleted(object sender, PeekCompletedEventArgs args)
     {
         MessageQueue mq = (MessageQueue)sender;
         if (mq != null)
         {
             try
             {
                 if (Log.IsInfoEnabled)
                 {
                     Log.InfoFormat("[{0}] Starting processing message queue {1}", _endpoint.RouteName, _queue.QueueName);
                 }
                 mq.EndPeek(args.AsyncResult);
                 MessageQueueTransaction transaction = new MessageQueueTransaction();
                 transaction.Begin();
                 Message message = mq.Receive(transaction);
                 ... // omitted for simplicity
```

I cannot access the client server from the DB server hence I need to have the message queue on the same DB server since I am sending the message to the queue from SQL

I have checked the following:

1. No issue sending the message from SQL
2. No n/w accessibility issue between servers
3. Un-authenitcated RPC calls are enable in the Message queuing server security properties
4. Queue format is correct. I am using direct OS format. Have also tried with TCP format specifying the IP address instead of machine name

But to no avail. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What is the queue address?

Comment: Also did this work before and stopped working?

Answer (score 0):

If this has worked before and stopped working, your problem is almost certainly due to a change in DTC on either sender or receiver, a change to the firewall, or both.

According to [this guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700128(v=vs.85).aspx) you may need to:

> ...configure both the queue computer and the client computer to enable
>   network DTC access.

and

> ...configure Windows Firewall to add MS DTC to the list of exceptions.

If this has never worked, then it could be one of several other issues, but as stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms699854(v=vs.85).aspx), remote reads are "not part of the optimal messaging model", ie the optimal paradigm adopted for MSMQ is *send-remote, read-local*. Consider changing your architecture not to use remote reads.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I hear you regarding remote reads and understand its not the recommended model. We are trying to take some heavy load off the application by creating a SQL scheduled job and have that execute an SP that sends a message to the message queue. The issue is that the application server is not accessible from the DB server, hence the queue has to reside on the Db server and I was hoping I could do a remote read from the application server. I will try to check the DTC settings and firewall settings as you suggested. Thanks